# PHP MPM_PREFORK for +4000 users

Tags: apache, load, multiple-users

I have the next mpm_prefork settings:

`StartServers 1024
MinSpareServers 128
MaxSpareServers 1024
MaxClients 2048
ServerLimit 2048`

With this config I'm able to have around 1700 users before getting connection reset error for the rest of the users.

The server has 32GB ram and six cores. Before getting connection reset, htop shows max 5gb of use.

Any idea on what to do to achieve +4000 concurrent users?